# Make Onedrive files offline available on Windows Phone

Tags: sync, onedrive, storage

I have set my OneDrive-Settings on my Windows 8.1 machine to offline available. On my Windows Phone 8.1 I find no option to do this. This is pretty annyoing to always have to wait for the download.
Am I missing some options on Windows Phone 8.1 to set this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available yet, bit planned (no eta though). http://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6380014-offline-access-on-windows-phone